# Browser compatible word wrap and whitespace: pre?

Tags: css

I need text within a div to be preserved and to wrap. So far I am having a tough time coming up with a solution. The best solution I've been able to find doesn't work for all browsers.

The following works in Chrome and IE6+, but in Firefox the text is not wrapping.

```
 white-space: pre; 
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

I've found that for whatever reason the text does not wrap in Firefox with white-space:pre. And -moz-pre-wrap does not work in Firefox 3.5 (why??), only pre-wrap. BUT when I add pre-wrap to the list, IE 6 and 7 don't work. Very frustrating.

The code:

```
.introsub {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 550px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em; 
  white-space: pre; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the text automatically wrapped by default?

Can you show me some example code?

Comment: I thought that it would be, but it's not. .introsub {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 550px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em; 
  white-space: pre; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

Comment: Issue view on codeplex seems to be suffering from this.

Comment: Pretty much every browser does word-wrap pretty much everywhere by default. Generally the question is how to turn it _off_. Methinks if you're asking "how to turn it on" you're already asking the wrong question. The question I'd ask is "why the @#$%& isn't it on by default?" Probably what's screwing up is something weird on some seemingly-unrelated element much higher up in the cascade that gets inherited everywhere. Can you point to a complete working example somewhere so we can examine _all_ the code (including the parts that don't seem relevant)?

Comment: TLDR: `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Answer (score 34):

The CSS3 properties don't always work as we would like them to work :).
Still, I don't see a point in mixing `white-space:pre` and `word-wrap:break-word`.

The former will not wrap the text unless a `<br />` tag is encountered. The second one will do the opposite: break the words whenever it's necessary, even in the middle of a word. They seem to be in conflict, and the most obvious answers to why different browsers react differently to these properties is that

- they support either of the two properties
- since they are in conflict, the precedence is undefined or different in each browser

(I can't be sure though, I'm not really an expert here).

I suggest you take a closer look at [this](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp) and then decide on what should be used in your particular case.

[EDIT]

You might want to try this (should work in ALL browsers):

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* ancient Opera */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* newer Opera */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome; W3C standard */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
```

I haven't tested this, but I believe it should do the trick for you.

Comment: What is your solution for all browsers to word wrap? I've tried many different combinations, but this is the only one I've found would work with most browsers (excluding Firefox). But I need Firefox to work as well. If I don't have word-wrap:break-word, then IE6 & 7 will not work. But I cannot use pre-wrap, which works in Firefox 3.5 b/c it also does not work in IE6 or 7.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had tried this as well, but it does not work in IE6 or IE7. Really, I would just be happy if it worked in these two AND firefox (the other browsers aren't AS important), but so far I have found no solution. :[

Comment: Supporting IE6 and IE7 is the worst thing you can do anyway, it's because of them web programmers lose hair :D. I don't add support for these even in large scale projects ;). Still, word-wrap should work in them, I think it was implemented in IE5.5.

Comment: I used the css for 'pre' and it worked even in IE7. No scrollbars!

Answer (score 33):

I know this is a very old issue, but since I have just ran into it I feel the urge to answer.

My solution would be:

Use `white-space: pre-wrap;` as it is nearly the same as `white-space: pre;`, just adds linebreaks. (reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html)

Then I would specifically target *old-ie* with either conditional comments (reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) or with browser specific css hacks (http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/).

An example for the second method:

```
.introsub {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 550px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em; 
  white-space: pre-wrap; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

/* IE6 and below */
* html .introsub  { white-space: pre  }

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html .introsub { white-space: pre  }
```

This will be enough to force it to wrap.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you want to see paragraphs and the text wraps, white-space: pre-wrap; works perfectly

Comment: I'd like to note that using @SoonDead suggestion on a `<pre>` tag (in opposed to `<div>`) worked the best for me. My use case was that I needed to preserve formatting when copying text from a `<div>`. Using `white-space: pre-wrap` wrapped the displayed text, but formatting was gone on copy+paste (though not on copy+special paste). I changed `<div>` to `<pre>` and it then worked.