# Browser compatible word wrap and whitespace: pre? (take 2)

Tags: css

Ok, someone in the cosmos must know the answer to this.

I've already asked this question here but still no solution.

I need text within a div to be preserved and to wrap. So far I am having a tough time coming up with a solution. The best solution I've been able to find doesn't work for all browsers.

The following works in Chrome and IE6+, but in Firefox the text is not wrapping.

```
 white-space: pre; 
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

I've found that for whatever reason the text does not wrap in Firefox with white-space:pre. And -moz-pre-wrap does not work in Firefox 3.5 (why??), only pre-wrap. BUT when I add pre-wrap to the list, IE 6 and 7 don't work. Very frustrating.

The code:

```
.introsub {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 550px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em; 
  white-space: pre; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Also, I've tried:

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* ancient Opera */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* newer Opera */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome; W3C standard */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
```

and it does not work in IE6 or 7.

Thanks

Comment: Does this question differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413015/browser-compatible-word-wrap-and-whitespace-pre ?

Comment: You want the text to be preserved? What do you mean by that? Also, DIVs wrap text by default.

Comment: I need line-breaks to be preserved, not so much spaces between letters. It does wrap by default but it doesn't preserve the line breaks in the text. So if the div contains text where it has two lines with 5 blank lines in-between it will be preserved. This is not for displaying code. @Alvaro it is the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this for a while:

```
div{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if `font-family: monospace;` makes a difference here, but `white-space: pre-wrap;` worked for me on its own.

Comment: @MichaelBremerkamp No, monospaced font is not related to white space collapsing, it's only there to display source code (a typical use case) in a readable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It will work in IE8+, Chrome, FF and Safari

```
div {
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    div {
        white-space: normal !important;
    }
}
```